# ¿Por qué funciona opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'path') pero opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"') no como una opción a Selenium4?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, rutas, selenium-webdriver, depuración

Me he dado cuenta de algo muy extraño al intentar implementar un `Chome driver` usando el `--user-data-dir` y el `--profile-directory` del usuario en `Python 3.9.7`, vean a continuación:

Sí ejecutan el siguiente código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

Obtiene con éxito una instancia de `Chrome driver` utilizando la correspondiente `--user-data-dir` y el `--profile-directory`:

[image: preview1]

Ahora, **después de eliminar todas las instancias del `Chrome driver` usando el siguiente código en** `cmd`:

```
taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe
```

Y luego compilando **este** otro código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

path = input('Introduce YOUR profile path:')

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

Para finalmente pasar `C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` como entrada al programa

**Obtiene el siguiente error:**

> WebDriverException: unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port
> file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at
> "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
> is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process

¿Por qué sucede esto?

¿No es `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"')` una forma válida de pasar esta ruta de datos de usuario:

`path = C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` ?

Comment: será por que estas poniendo comillas en la ruta? `fr'"{path}"'` (pones comillas simple que son para declarar un string pero dentro de ese string pones comillas dobles que no tienen sentido para tu contexto)

Comment: lo que `fr'"{path}"'` retorna es `'"C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"'`

Comment: Sucede que `C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` se pasa como string pero para que sea leída como una ruta y añadida como opción a Selenium, se debe poner dentro de unos signos ortográficos anteponiendo una r, así `r''` , es lo que tengo entendido, pero al ser pasada esa cadena dentro de una variable como `path` hago uso de `f""` bajo el mismo argumento de `r''` @Christian

Comment: hay incongruencias en lo que dices, pues en tu primer ejemplo no pones dobles comillas, solo una e indicando que se trata de un *raw-tring*. Intenta hciendo `fr'{path}'` y si sigues teniendo problemas trata de usar `r'{0}'.format(path)`

Comment: ¡Eureka! ¡`fr'{path}'` ha resuelto mi problema! Deseas poner dicho comentario como respuesta al post para que te de el ✅ ? @Christian

Comment: Es un problema raro. Las comillas dobles están bien, acabo de probarlo. No necesitas siquiera usar selenium para comprobarlo. Debe haber algo más, puesto que lo comentaste en otras preguntas. De hecho, si no las usas, cuando la ruta que indica tiene espacios, chrome no inicia correctamente.

Comment: @Mateo el problema es que usa 2 tipos de comillas donde solo se necessta de 1 tipo  que es para declarar el string :/

Comment: Sí :( es que había intentado de varias formas poder lograr hacerle entender al programa que el usuario estaba pasando una ruta correcta para ser usada como opción, pero simplemente no podía dar con la sintaxis @Mateo

Comment: @NoahVerner mm... no lo sé, esto puede entrar en la categoría de errores ortográficos. De igual puedes ponerlo tu como respuesta

Comment: Lo hacía era porque pensaba que estas comillas `''` sólo podían usarse con `r` así como estas `""` con `f`, es por la costumbre @Christian

Comment: jaja, cualquiera de esas 2 sirven para declarar un string. No te preocupes todos nos confundimos de vez en cuando :D

Comment: @NoahVerner puedes usar cualquiera de las 2 comillas para definir un literal de string. Eso también es muy positivo porque puedes usar las otras comillas y no tener que escapar las que quieres usar. Ejemplo: `' "Hola" '` es equivalente a `" \"Hola\" "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el problema gracias a @Christian, simplemente estaba cometiendo un error ortográfico, así que cambié `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"')` por `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'{path}')`, el código quedaría así:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

path = input('Introduce YOUR profile path:')

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'{path}') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

Después de compilar no genera ningún error, y se obtiene el mismo resultado del primer código mostrado en el post.